# How to check if file is in downloadmanager queue?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

The user has to download multiple files which will start on a button click. The code will check if a file already exists, if not then it adds it to the download queue. I am adding all the non-existent files to the download queue.

But if the user clicks on the button again immediately, the files get re-added to the download queue. So how to check if the file is added to the download manager queue? If it is added then, the file will not be re-added.

Comment: everytime you request download you get unique id back, you can store ids and later check with `getUriForDownloadedFile` if file is already in the queue

Comment: it says `getUriFodDownloadedFile` works only for successfully downloaded file. I want to get a list of queued files.

Comment: well you can always maintain it, right? it won't give you access to files downloaded by other apps anyway

Comment: I'll have to store the URIs and then maintain the list for failed downloads etc...need to update it every download...basically if the goes to other activities then, this becomes painful...as download manager is a system service, hence I suppose there won't be any such command as I am requesting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use `DownloadManager.Query`

Here is example you can refer [Download manager example](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/11/download-using-downloadmanager.html)

sample code

```
DownloadManager.Query query = null;
Cursor c = null;
DownloadManager downloadManager = null;
downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
query = new DownloadManager.Query();
 if(query!=null) {
            query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED|DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED|DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL|
                    DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING|DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING);
        } else {
            return;
        }
c = downloadManager.query(query);
if(c.moveToFirst()) { 
int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)); 
switch(status) { 
case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED: 
break; 
case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING: 
break; 
case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING: 
break; 
case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL: 
break;  
}
}
```